# How export render view to HTML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I export all my rendered view to an html file? I want to save the view to a file rather than display it to the screen. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `render` call `render_to_string` and save the returned string into an file.
(see: http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Rendering/render_to_string)

Answer (score 0):

This sort of sounds like Dynamic Page Caching. There is a Railscasts on this topic. It is rather dated, unless you subscribe (there is a revised version with subscription).

http://railscasts.com/episodes/169-dynamic-page-caching